# Maven: Failed to execute goal heroku:deploy-war

Tags: java, maven, heroku, intellij-idea

I am following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea#setting-up-the-heroku-maven-plugin) tutorial to create a sample project in IntelliJ Idea and deploy it in Heroku, but when I run the project

[image]

the Maven didn't built properly, giving me error:

> Failed to execute goal com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:1.1.3:deploy-war (default-cli) on project helloworld: Failed to deploy application: Could not find app name: No 'heroku' remote found.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. The tutorial is missing one line. Before running this, we have to do

> mvn clean install